# Scheduled Toast showing multiple times

Tags: windows-8

I have a calendar application which has the ability to set pill reminders.

```
ScheduledToastNotification recurringToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(
toastXml,startDay.AddDays(1), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0), 3);
```

As you can see it has MaxSnoozeCount = 3 and SnoozeInterval = 1 minute. The problem is that when I click the appearing toast as the documentation states the toast should be shown again because it hasn't been "snoozed". Yet it appears exactly 4 times regardless of the fact that I click it each single time.

Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon clicking on the scheduled toast, your app should handle the toast activation event and remove the scheduled toast to prevent it from being seen again.  A scheduled toast will continue to be shown based on its creation parameters until an application explicitly removes it from the schedule.

Use [`ToastNotifier.GetScheduledToastNotifications`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.getscheduledtoastnotifications.aspx) to retrieve the toast of interest, and then call [`ToastNotifier.RemoveFromSchedule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.removefromschedule) to stop it from being displayed in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I though that I have to remove it but at least to me the documentation sounds like once you lunch the app from the reminder it will be removed.